# When and how to initialize standard I/O streams (stdin, stdout, stderr)?

Tags: c, libc, c89

Experimenting with static binaries, I found myself reimplementing parts of libc.  My libc is static (i.e. a .a archive,) targets 64-bit Linux only and will probably never be POSIX compliant but I'm willing to go after the low-hanging fruit at least.

My question concerns my rudimentary stdio implementation.  From what I have I have read, I have to make sure stdin, stdout, and stderr are available on program startup.  Is it enough for me to have in one of my library source files.

```
static FILE* _files[FOPEN_MAX];

_files[0] = /* open stdin */; 
_files[1] = /* open stdout */; 
_files[2] = /* open stderr */; 

FILE* stdin =  _files[0];
FILE* stdout = _files[1];
FILE* stderr = _files[2];
```

and in stdio.h

```
extern FILE* stdin;
extern FILE* stdout;
extern FILE* stderr;
```

Or is there more to be done?

Comment: You say that you are not seeking full POSIX compliance, but are you seeking full ISO C compliance? If not, then your question does not make sense, because your question "is there more to be done?" can only be answered by yourself, since you are the only one who knows what level of compliance you want to achieve.

Comment: I am seeking to achieve as much compliance as I can with as little effort as I can. :-)  So, is what I have given enough for standards compliance or  does ISO c89 (sorry not POSIX) require more?  I don't have the standard document itself which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: I assume that your previous comment was intended as a reply to me. If you want someone to be notified of your reply, then you must use the `@` syntax together with the name of the person in your comment. Otherwise, that person will not be notified of your reply (unless they are following the post that the comment is attached to or they are the owner of that post), and will therefore probably not notice your reply. Press the "Help" button when writing a comment in order to read more about the `@` syntax.

Comment: You can read the exact requirements of the ISO C11 standard concerning I/O in the C standard library [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21). If that is too much legalese for you, then [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) may provide a better overview.

Comment: You will probably also have to implement your own `struct FILE`. This `struct` must contain the underlying file descriptor, an end-of-file indicator and an error indicator. If you want to implement buffering, then the `struct` will need to contain more information.